# Can we determine the location of a radio station if we know the wavelength and frequency of radio wave emitted by that radio station?

Tags: waves, radio, radio-frequency

let say that we can detect the wavelength and frequency of radio wave then can we detect that from where these radio waves are coming or from how much distance these waves are coming?

Comment: That's a simple geometric triangulation problem. It has been used for pre-GPS navigation throughout most of the 20th century.

Comment: You also need the direction, not just the wavelength/frequency

Comment: You appear to be suggesting that if you know the speed of the radio waves then you can find the distance. But you do not know how long (time) the waves took to reach you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to walk around a bit, you can triangulate a radio source. It helps to have the frequency (wavelength is just $\frac{c}{\lambda}$) to tune your receiver.

This is the principle behind the [avalanche beacon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_transceiver)

A directional antenna will help you pick the direction of the source; moving at right angles to the direction you will get a different angle, and this will help you know if the target is in front or behind you. You repeat this process until you find the exact location of the source.

If you have *exact* phase information from a transmitter, you can use that to determine the distance; and again with a directional antenna you can determine the direction (although in reality *multipath* reflections will corrupt the signal).

You might want to read about the old DECCA and LORAL navigation systems that were based on some of these principles (note - they used one transmitter to help determine the absolute phase of the other.... But in principle if you had a REALLY accurate clock synced with the oscillator of the transmitter, you could get the distance within a meter or better. That's more or less the principle of GPS...

Answer (score 0):

First off, detecting the wavelength and the frequency is redundant (assuming free space propagation) these are related by $c=f \lambda$ (speed of light = frequency times wavelength).

*Single Site Measurement*

If you know the absolute intensity of the signal that the object is emmitting, and you are dealing with (essentially) free space propagation, then you can use the $1/r^2$ decay of the intensity to get back the current distance.  Suppose that you measure and intensity $I_0$ when you are a distance $r_0$ away (maybe this is a calibration step).  Then you know that for other distances the observed intensity is given by $I=I_0 (r_0/r)^2$, which you can solve for $r$ if desired.  In astronomy, the term "[standard candle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/stdcand.html)" is used for the objects whose intrinsic intensities are known well enough that you can reliably generate distance measurements from intensity measurements.

*Multiple Observing Locations*

Unless you're working with a standard candle, you need to observe the object from multiple perspectives in order to estimate the distance.
The first is to measure the [parallax](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/para.html) that arises when observing the object from two distinct locations.  If you have two well separated sensors and accurate clocks, you can also do [time difference of arrival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) to triangulate the position of the emitter.

Comment: The amateur radio community will tell you that the concept of a standard candle is useless given the varying propagation conditions in the atmosphere. Conditions change on length scales from hous to decades.

Comment: @JonCuster point taken.